# Could not resolve project : realm

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, npm, node-modules

I am working in a old project can't build this project. Upgraded older version to new version gradle. I can't run this project. First time I am building android older project. Previously project used react native previous version. I converted older version dependencies in to new version.

This is my build.gradle(app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amsec.cwII"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 11
        versionName "3.1.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

.......

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-keychain')
    implementation project(':react-native-fingerprint-scanner')
    implementation project(':realm')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:'
    //  compile project(':react-native-appstore-version-checker')
    // From node_modules
    implementation files('libs/jsoup-1.11.3.jar')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:17.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}
```

This is build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
       
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting these errors

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :realm.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :realm was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.2.1' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:71)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:161)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:186)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:150)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:146)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.lambda$select$0(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:160)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:147)
)
```

//This is my updated android gradle

```
all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinversion = "1.3.72"
    repositories {

        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinversion"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.11.1"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What's your realm version?

Comment: When I check in terminal by using this command  `npm realm --version`   I got version 6.14.17.But I checked inside package.json I got this: "realm": "^10.21.1".

Comment: I'll write an answer please tell me if it's work for you.

Comment: @LouaySleman I think almost this is the answer. Could you can help me to solve this Realm problem,

Comment: Can you share the code, and tell me how to reproduce it?

Comment: @LouaySleman I uploaded my updated android gradle in the question.The error I am getting exact same error in the question that is : `No matching configuration of project :realm was found. The consumer was configured to find a...........`

Comment: can you can share the whole project on github?

Comment: @LouaySleman Can i share the project without my project code ,I mean without my own code ? Then also you can check right. Because this issues is not my code problem it's because of other dependencies and all issues.  Please understand me. I didn't get anyone to solve this, please help me. So can i share ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin` dependency to the `buildscript.dependencies` block.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.11.1"
    }
}
```

You can check the documentation from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/install/).

To fix kotlin error just add in `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

Comment: I went to the document that you are given. when adding  `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`  these two lines giving error when gradle build time.  Error is: `> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found. But without adding these two lines gradle build is success.

Comment: but project building  time getting the exact same error that mentioned in the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer please can you check it if it's solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks your last answer solved my kotlin issue .But when I run the project I am still getting the realm error.